# Redirect to login page if user is not logged in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

http://localhost/finsafe/calculator/sip.html

If i type the above url I want it to redirect to my login page

Following is my code

```
if(!is_user_logged_in() && curPageURL() = 'http://localhost/finsafe/calculator/sip.html') {
wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/finsafe/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocal%3A8095%2Ffinsafe%2Fcontact%2F/', 302 );
exit;
}



function curPageURL() {

$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}

$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}

return $pageURL;
}
```

But it doesnt work can anyone help

Comment: For the love of god please secure that shit before people start abusing it! How can I PM you? what's your email?

Comment: Seriously, what do you not get about securing this up? I Can delete your whole site and have been able to since you posted this question. Now please set a password on your db RIGHT NOW! I really do honestly hope you're not hosting these sites for clients because they are all terribly unsecure and can be hacked/deleted in a flash!!

Comment: Thanks scott, here after i would be careful

Comment: Just make sure you set a password on your Phpmyadmin otherwise your whole database is exposed to the public!!! Phpmyadmin even tells you this at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah, I have password for database phpmyadmin.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your page is a .html file and you're trying to run PHP code on it. You'll need to save your `.html` file out as a `.php` file instead and then try again. Then wrap your PHP code in php tags like so...

```
<?php

if(!is_user_logged_in() && curPageURL() = 'http://localhost/finsafe/calculator/sip.html') {
wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/finsafe/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F183.82.33.232%3A8095%2Ffinsafe%2Fcontact%2F/', 302 );
exit;
}

function curPageURL() {

$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}

$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}

return $pageURL;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but right now i must use .html, is there any way to do it

Comment: There's no way to do it with just HTML. The PHP won't work unless it's in a PHP file.

Comment: Ohh, ok Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

 if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/', 301 ); 
  exit;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, still it doesnt work can you explain about is_page('slug') in your if condition

Comment: is_page('page_slug'), here slug is which is shown in url. like is_page('home').

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Force login plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check like this also :

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo "user logged in";
} else {
    header('Location: ' . wp_login_url());
}
```